# How do I know if I can defer a JS script on my web page?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a [magento site](http://www.princessly.com/) which has a very heavy theme that I'm trying to optimize. It uses quite some JS scripts that when I'm testing the site speed it's recommended to me should be deferred.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/skin/frontend/default/forest_fashion/js/prototype.and.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/media/js/f8a453ce8ffc122a8a56247434d1ac82.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/skin/frontend/default/forest_fashion/js/princessly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/skin/frontend/default/forest_fashion/js/overlaybox.js"></script>
```

But I never wrote all the JS code so I'm not sure if I can simply add a defer attribute to the script tags without breaking anything because I also heard despite adding defer attribute would make my site render faster client side some features may rely on the script being parsed before the page is rendered.

Is this true? Can I simply add defer to any JS script on my page without first discriminating? How do I know if I can safely add a defer attribute to a script on my page?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is meant to be loaded before page load then adding it after page load would cause errors.

e.g. this particular code block will not execute if the page has already loaded

```
window.addEventListeners('load',function(){
    //do stuff
    alert('Foo');
},false);
```

So I am **99%** sure that by simply adding a `defer` attribute will NOT make code problem free. It will all depend on how it was meant to be used.